# IIS 500 error on postback or upload on some computers

Tags: asp.net, iis

I run a website on IIS 8.5 and ASP.NET. I recently moved my website to a new server. Some users are getting an internal server error when trying to postback or upload on the site. As an example, when they try to reply in the forum (I use YetAnotherForum), they will get the error page.

I think I've narrowed it down to postbacks. Whenever there is a postback, they will get the error. This includes using ASP.NET buttons on the page.

My big problem is that the error is not logged anywhere. It is not in the event viewer, failed request logs, or even the server log. I have all application errors caught and logged in Global.asax, but the error never reaches the handler. The users just get the error on the screen and it doesn't seem to be recognized at all by the server. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[Generic IIS Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JJ5N.png)

As you can see, it is a very generic IIS error.

I am still maintaining a test site on my old server. I sent one person that was getting the error to the test site to see if he got the error. He did not - he only gets the error on the new site on the new server. I'm guessing it must be some setting I am missing.

Only a select few users are getting the error. The ones I have talked to are using Windows 10. They have tried all of the different browsers (IE, Firefox, and Chrome), and none of them work. I also have Windows 10, but I do not get the error.

Any chance someone has seen this error and knows the fix?

Comment: You should look at the website if there is some sort of [global exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) and logging. Having the stacktrace should give you more information. As some kind of last resort you could change the custom error mode for a few moments. That should display a detailed error on the client screen.

Comment: I do have global exception handling, but the error never gets caught. It is like it never even happens (except that the user is sent to my custom error page). I have changed the custom error mode to off, which is how I got the screenshot of the error. However, it is never logged or caught anywhere else.